# I have algorithm for finding maximum flow. Does it have an author or name?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

I'm beginner in programming and I'm learning algorithms to find maximum flows.

Most of them are rather difficult such as Ford-Falkerson, Edmunds-Karp and Dinitz. The problem is here: https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1694

I found an algorithm that finds maximum flow just for one depth first search for O(n+m). What is the name or author of this algorithm? This solution uses just one DFS. All standard algorithms use many DFS or BFS searches, but not this. I'm a bit confused.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<pair<int, long long>>> adj;
vector<bool> visited;

long long dfs(int to) {
    long long r = 0;
    visited[to] = true;
    for (const auto& [from, flow]: adj[to]) {
        if (from == 1 || visited[from]) {
            r += flow;
        } else {
            r += min(flow, dfs(from));
        }
    }
    return r;
}

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    adj.resize(n + 1);
    visited.resize(n + 1, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int from, to, flow;
        cin >> from >> to >> flow;
        adj[to].push_back({from, flow});
    }
    cout << dfs(n);
}
```

Can you help me to understand why Dinitz or Edmunds-Karp, with O(m<sup>2</sup>n) complexity, are needed?

Comment: The algorithm you posted does not find a maximum flow in an arbitrary graph.  Maybe you mistook its purpose, or maybe it just doesn't work.

Comment: "I found an algorithm"  Where?  Have you tested if it does what you think it does?

Comment: I found this algorithm in hacking section at https://cses.fi/problemset/hack/1694/list/
This program passed all 13 tests, but I understand it failed on David Eisenstat's test below.

Anyway, I continue to study solutions, that really must work, such as Edmonds-Karp algorithm and others.

Thanks for your replies :)

Answer (score 2):

Breaks on the following graph since the second visit to v will incorrectly assume that there is one unit of flow available to pull:

[image: There is an arc from the source to v with capacity one, and two arcs from v to the sink with capacity two.]

Comment: The algorithm may not find a flow in this graph, but this graph found a flaw in the algorithm.